# Tailwindcss not working for react project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, configuration, tailwind-css, vite

I am trying to integrate tailwind to my React-typescript project created with vite.
Followed Tailwind configuration guide step by step, but I am now getting this warning:

```
warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

This is my directory structure:

```
│   .eslintrc.json
│   .gitignore
│   .prettierrc
│   index.html
│   package-lock.json
│   package.json
│   postcss.config.cjs
│   tailwind.config.cjs
│   tsconfig.json
│   tsconfig.node.json
│   vite.config.ts
│
├───.vscode
│       settings.json
│
├───public
│       litaci-logo.png
│       litaci.png
│
└───src
    │   App.tsx
    │   index.css
    │   main.tsx
    │   vite-env.d.ts
    │
    ├───components
    │       Navbar.tsx
    │
    ├───containers
    │       Page.tsx
    │
    ├───pages
    │       Root.tsx
    │
    └───store
```

tailwind.config.cjs

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}',
    './src/pages/**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}',
    './src/containers/**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

It was working fine before I added .prettierrc file.
I followed this [github discussion](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/7621) but to no avail.
Tailwindcss class is not working at all.

Comment: Try to remove spaces between file extensions: `{js, jsx, ts, tsx}` -> `{js,jsx,ts,tsx}`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thank you! it's working. I can be so stupid at times.

Comment: Glob patterns are very sensitive sadly

Answer (score 0):

In my next project styles not applied only in  src/pages directory. So just hardcode and add to every page import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css"

Finally that's worked for me

// src/pages/about.tsx
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).